# regular expression, multiple parentheses and square brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parentheses, square-bracket

**Answer from @avinash-raj:**

```
re.findall(r'\([^\[\]()]*\[\([^\[\]()]+source=([\w./]+)', s)
```

**Modified question:**

I have the following string:

```
s=string='s=<a=1 b=[(text1 [(text2 source=x.gz i=i.gz)]), ([(text3 j=1.0 source=y.gz)])] c=[([(3)])] d=[([(source=x.gz)])]>'
```

I want to get this list as an output:

```
['x.gz','y.gz']
```

**Original question:**

I have the following string:

```
s=string='s=<a=1 b=[([(source=x.gz i=0)]), ([(j=1 source=y.gz)])] c=[([(3)])]>'
```

I want to get this list as an output:

```
['x.gz','y.gz']
```

I have tried this:

```
re.findall(r'b=\[([^]]*)\]',s)
```

Which returns:

```
['([(source=x.gz i=0)']
```

I have also tried this:

```
re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]',s)
```

Which returns:

```
['([(source=x.gz i=0)', '(j=1 source=y.gz)', '([(3)']
```

I am equally happy for a one line answer or being pointed to a tutorial, which enables me to find the answer myself upon completion of it. Thanks.

**EDIT1: Changed string (see answers below):**

```
s=string='s=<a=1 b=[([(source=x.gz i=0)]), ([(j=1 source=y.gz)])] c=[([(3)])] source=4>'
```

**EDIT2: Changed string (no answers provided, but I'll provide it myself):**

```
s=string='s=<a=1 b=[(text1 [(text2 source=x.gz i=i.gz)]), ([(text3 j=1.0 source=y.gz)])] c=[([(3)])] d=[([(source=x.gz)])]>'
```

I tried this:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=b=)\[\(.*?[\S]*?source=([\w\./]+)', s)
```

But it only returns:

```
['x.gz']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to capture the characters that you want to print.

```
>>> string = 's=<a=1 b=[([(source=x.gz i=0)]), ([(j=1 source=y.gz)])] c=[([(3)])] source=4>'
>>> re.findall(r'\(\[\([^\[\]()]*source=([\w.]+)', string)
['x.gz', 'y.gz']
```

**Explanation:**

- `\(\[\(` Matches `([(` characters literally.
- `[^\[\]()]*` A negated character class which matches any character but not of `[` or `]` or `(` or `)` zero or more times.
- `source=` Matches the string `source=`
- `([\w.]+)` Captures word character or a dot one or more times.

**Update:**

```
>>> string = 's=<a=1 b=[(text1 [(text2 source=x.gz i=i.gz)]), ([(text3 j=1.0 source=y.gz)])] c=[([(3)])] d=[([(source=x.gz)])]>'
>>> re.findall(r'\([^\[\]()]*\[\([^\[\]()]+source=([\w.]+)', string)
['x.gz', 'y.gz']
```

Comment: What's would be the expected output for the updated one?

Comment: check my update. Let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: my previous regex, `\(\[\([^\[\]()]*source=([\w.]+)` would work. What's wrong with this?

Comment: No, I double checked. It returns ['y.gz', 'x.gz'] instead of ['x.gz', 'y.gz'].

Comment: try this `\([^\[\]()]*\[\([^\[\]()]+source=([\w.]+)`

Comment: Works! Let's close it here. I've wasted too much of your time. Uber grateful!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the `source` value, perhaps you could use this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'source=([\w\.]+)', s)
['x.gz', 'y.gz']
```

This regex specifies that whatever appears after `source=` should be captured, as long as it is a period `.`, or an alpha-numeric character.

**Edit**: For your updated string:

```
>>> s = 's=<a=1 b=[([(source=x.gz i=0)]), ([(j=1 source=y.gz)])] c=[([(3)])] source=4>'
>>> re.findall(r'\[\([\w=\s]*source=([\w\.]+)', s)
['x.gz', 'y.gz']
```

Now the regex specifies that `source=` must be preceded by `[(` and by zero or more characters in the set `[\w=\s]` (alpha-numerics, `=`, spaces).

**Edit 2**: Pretty much the same as above, except `[\w=\s]` is expanded to include `.`:

```
>>> s = 's=<a=1 b=[(text1 [(text2 source=x.gz i=i.gz)]), ([(text3 j=1.0 source=y.gz)])] c=[([(3)])] d=[([(source=x.gz)])]>'
>>> re.findall(r'\[\([\w=\.\s]*source=([\w\.]+)', s)
['x.gz', 'y.gz', 'x.gz']
```

Comment: That works for the question I asked. I have modified the string (adding source=4 at the end), so your solution will fail. I should have been more specific.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen No problem. Looks like the other answers explain things nicely, but I've updated anyway :-)

Comment: I probably marked this one as answered too fast. I made a second edit to the string. I'm struggling to get all matches. Module re is not my friend - yet! :)

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Another update to my answer... Does this get any closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, except the expected output is still ['x.gz','y.gz']. See answer from @avinash-raj in the comment box below his answer. I'll play around with it and post my solution.

Answer (score 2):

This regex finds all source= inside parentesis.

```
s='s=<a=1 b=[([(source=x.gz i=0)]), ([(j=1 source=y.gz)])] c=[([(3)])]>'
re.findall(r"source=(\S+?)(?:\s|[)])",s)
['x.gz', 'y.gz']
```

If you want only those inside ([( and )])

```
re.findall(r"[(]\[[(][\s\S]*?source=([\w\.]+)[\s\S]*?[)]\][)]",s)
```

I also batled regex since college, but since I started reading this [PERL regex guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) I started to like regex.

Comment: This one works as well. I'm currently looking at the answer by @avinash-raj. Thank you for the link to the tutorial. I need to sit down one day and spend an entire day with regexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nice feature from [the new regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that allows to extract all the results from a repeated capture group. Note that this same module allows to use duplicate named captures too.

Example:

```
import regex

s = 's=<a=1 b=[([(source=x.gz i=0)]), ([(j=1 source=y.gz)])] c=[([(3)])] source=4>'

# description of an element 
elt = r'''\( [^[]* \[\(
        (?>
            \b source=(?<source> [^\s)]+ )
          |
            [^s)]+
          |
            \Bs+
          |
            s(?!ource=)
        )*
        \)\]\)
'''
p = regex.compile(r'b=\[%s(?:,\ *%s)*' % (elt, elt), regex.VERBOSE);

m = p.search(s)

print(m.captures('source'))
```

result:

```
['x.gz', 'y.gz']
```

The main interest of this approach is that you can deal with an undefined number of elements and ensure that these elements are from the value you have choosen (a, b, c ...) at the same time.

Note that for this approach the `findall` method is no more needed since the repeatition is in the pattern itself, so the `search` method suffice.

Comment: Is there a need to optimize like this `[^s)]+|\Bs+|s(?!ource=)`? It makes the regex hard to understand and maintain, IMO.

Comment: @nhahtdh: It's clearly the best way to do it. I don't think that it is less clear than something like that `(?:(?!source=).)*` that is not more readable and inefficient.

Comment: `(?:(?!source=).)*` is only a single place to understand, whereas you have to combine the 3 alternation to understand what the regex is trying to do in your case. You might be used to reading those, but think of the next people who have to maintain the code.

Comment: @nhahtdh: the "next people" must take the time to learn this kind of idiomatic subpattern.

Comment: Yep, but the other way is less error prone and easier to understand than your method.

Comment: Thanks, in regex performance first and in second place elegance...the x modifier can break the pattern and add comment to understand any regex.

Answer (score 0):

This will also generate the result:

```
re.findall(r'source=([a-z]+\.[a-z]+)',s,re.I)
['x.gz', 'y.gz']
```

works fine on all edits. **re.I** sets **case insensitive** flag.

Comment: It would for the original question and EDIT1. Please see EDIT2. I need to be careful to be specific when asking regex question. Thank you.

Comment: It works, but it breaks too easily. If I change source=x.gz to source=0.gz or source=4 to source=z.gz, then it's broken.